# Get correct CFHTTP run time, gettickcount inaccurate?

Tags: time, coldfusion, duration, cfhttp, gettickcount

I'm trying to troubleshoot a script and I'm 99% positive that its the CFHTTP function I'm running because when I remove it, the page seems to be much faster, but it's inconsistent.  That said, even when the page runs long, the tickcount that I'm outputting around the cfhttp request is short.  I'm not sure that CFHTTP is running inside the bounds of tickcount or not since its sending out the request for processing remotely.  When I isolate the two things, the tickcounts don't match up.

Does anyone know a way to get the time it takes to execute a CFHTTP function without using tickcount so I can test this properly?  I'm using CF9 (not 901 for certain reasons out of my control) so we don't have http logging either.

Thanks a bunch.
John

Comment: Show us your code that calculates the tick count. It does work.

Comment: I agree with @Miguel-F. I suspect you're mistaken about your assertion that getTickCount() isn't doing it's job properly: it's more likely you've got a glitch in your usage of it. Provide the code and a sample of its feedback. Also have you checked debug output to see how other files / method calls are contributing? Pls provide the execution time output from the request too.